# Why can't #Include work?

Tags: autohotkey

Why does this not work?

```
#Include D:\Data\Download\Scripts Latex2Unicode.ahk
```

It says

> Include file "D:\Data\Download\Scripts Latex2Unicode.ahk" cannot be opened. The program will exit.

It isn't different from the [help page](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm).

Comment: What happens when you run this? Start > Run > notepad "D:\Data\Download\Scripts Latex2Unicode.ahk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you mean:

```
    #Include D:\Data\Download\Scripts\Latex2Unicode.ahk
```

presuming the directory is "`Scripts`" and the file name "`Latex2Unicode.ahk`"

Let us know . . .

EDIT: Note, in the Help example:

```
    #Include C:\My Documents\Scripts\Utility Subroutines.ahk
```

the file name is "`Utility Subroutines.ahk`" in the "`Scripts`" directory -- the directory is not "`Utilities`" and the file name is not "`Subroutines.ahk`"